# How to insert variable into push method

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

```
  var userID = client.getFingerprint();

  var _paq = _paq || [];
  _paq.push(['setUserId', 'Place for userID']);
```

I just can't copy variable name without ' cause that does not work. How can I insert value of userID into 'Place for userID'?

Example value for userID is "1997040563"
It is generated by https://github.com/jackspirou/clientjs

As I said. I need to send that number. For ex. without variables code would be like:

```
  _paq.push(['setUserId', '1997040563']);
```

My question is how to transfer number from var userID to that placeholder for ID and keep it working.

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: http://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide#user-id

I'm trying to make it working. I generete fingerprint and save it into variable userID. Then I'd like to send that fingerprint into my database by the user-id feature. 

For now i know that this:
 _paq.push(['setUserId', userID]); 

does not work.

Comment: Ok. And what are you trying to do. Can you edit the question with an example value of userId, from where it comes and how you are trying to set the value

Comment: `_paq.push(['setUserId', userID]);`

Comment: And that was the first thing I tried. It is not working.

Comment: Why _paq.push(['setUserId', userID]) does not work? Throw an error?

Comment: No errors. It should insert userID into the database. Instead inserted value is "NULL". 

Everything is working when I run example code from question without variables.

Comment: The error must be in other place. Try to log the `_paq` variable and you note that its value will be ['setUserId', '1997040563'].

Comment: The getFingerprint is asynchronous? Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: I ran the: var test = "1234"; and that works fine. I guess the problem is in getFingerprint like elchininet said.

Comment: I agree with elchininet, the client.getFingerprint() must be an async call.

Comment: Is there any way to bypass it?